# Knob.js - Is there a way to link up dials so that they have a combined total?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I'm using the latest jQuery Knob.js and wondered if there is a way to link up 3 dials so that each value changes on "change" in order for the combined total to never go over 100%?

Initially all 3 dials are set to 33%. if a user changes one of the dial the other 2 should increase or decrease to equate to 100 in total.

Answer (score 0):

Because I liked the idea I've just created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kht38xps/) :

```
$(function () {
  $('.knob').knob({
    readOnly: false,
        'width': 150,
        'height': 150,
        'dynamicDraw': true,
        'thickness': 0.4,
        'tickColorizeValues': true,
        'skin': 'tron',
    displayInput: true,
    change: function (value) {
        var tKnobsVal = 0;
        $(".knob").each(function () {
            tKnobsVal += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        var kDiff = tKnobsVal - 100;
        adjustKnob(this.$.attr("id"), kDiff);
    }
});

$('#btn').click(function () {
    $({
        value: $('.knob').val()
    }).animate({
        value: 33
    }, {
        duration: 700,
        easing: 'swing',
        progress: function () {
            $('.knob').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
        }
    });
  });
});

function adjustKnob(id, value) {
  var cValue = value / 2;
  $(".knob").not("[id=" + id + "]").each(function () {
    changeKnob($(this).attr("id"), cValue);
  });
}

function changeKnob(id, value) {
  $({
    value: $("#" + id).val()
  }).animate({
    value: $("#" + id).val() - value
  }, {
    duration: 700,
    easing: 'swing',
    progress: function () {
        $("#" + id).val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
    }
  });
}
```

On the knob `change` event, the sum of all knob values is retrieved:

```
var tKnobsVal = 0;
$(".knob").each(function () {
            tKnobsVal += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
```

Then the function `adjustKnob()` is called with the value `var kDiff = tKnobsVal - 100;` (for the difference from 100) and the id of the knob that has been changed.
`adjustKnob()` then calls `changeKnob()` for every knob except the knob that was changed with half of `kDiff`.
In the Fiddle I added a button to set and reset all 3 knobs to the initial 33. Note that there is some finetuning missing (sometimes the sum of all knobs will equal a little bit above or less 100) but that's maybe caused e.g. by the sum of all knobs not having 100 as initial value because of the missing 1%.

Comment: I like it. I managed to get it to work after but it's still a little buggy. So my version changes the value immediately where as yours has a delay (which I quite like actually). There still seem to be some value deficiencies though as with mine. The values sometimes go over 100 if you keep changing it or 99% on 1 dial still leaves 1% on the other 2. Great work though dude